# How can i loop over a text file and find for spaces between the dates and times?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The text file is long i have many lines inside for example:

```
08/12/2014 00:59:41   Ok
08/12/2014 01:05:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:10:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:15:02   Ok
08/12/2014 01:20:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:25:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:30:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:35:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:40:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:45:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:50:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:55:01   Ok
08/12/2014 02:00:01   Ok
```

The spaces except the first lines in time between each written line is about 5 minutes.
What i need to do is loop over the text file and find the places that there is more then 5 minutes between two lines.

For example if i find a line `08/12/2014 01:50:01   Ok` and the line right after it is `08/12/2014 02:55:01   Ok` instead `08/12/2014 01:55:01   Ok` then write in a new text file this two lines.
So in the new text file i will see for example:

```
08/12/2014 01:50:01   Ok
08/12/2014 02:55:01   Ok
```

So i know there was a problem here.

I need somehow loop over the text file and find this places the time between each line is not like the others take this two lines and write them to a new text file.
So if in this text file i have like 10000 lines the new text file should have 4-5 lines.

This is how i'm creating and updating the text file now:

```
private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                span = new TimeSpan(0, (int)numericUpDown1.Value, 0);
                label21.Text = span.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
                timer3.Start();
            }
            else if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                label19.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                label19.Text = "חיבור האינטרנט והאתר תקינים";
                label19.Visible = true;
                timer3.Stop();
                if (timer1.Enabled != true)
                {
                    if (BeginDownload == true)
                    {
                        timer1.Start();
                    }
                }                
                bool fileok = Bad_File_Testing(combinedTemp);
                bool compared;
                if (fileok == true)
                {

                    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(combinedarchivefileanddir,true);
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "   Ok");
                        w.Close();
                    }
                    File1 = new Bitmap(combinedTemp);
                    try
                    {
                        compared = ComparingImages(File1);
                    }
                    catch (WebException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message + "\n\nCause: " + "Image not yet loaded.");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Delete(combinedTemp);
                }
                if (File1 != null)
                {
                    File1.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Inside this completed event i add the part:

```
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(combinedarchivefileanddir,true);
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "   Ok");
                        w.Close();
                    }
```

And i added just now a loop code to loop over the text file line by line:

```
private void ReadTextFile()
        {
            try
            {
                int counter = 0;
                string line;
                StreamReader file =
                   new StreamReader(combinedarchivefileanddir);
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //string t = line;
                    counter++;
                }

                file.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

How can i make now the calculation between each two lines and write the lines where the time and date spaces is not like the others to a new text file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could examine the `TotalMinutes` of the `TimeSpan` created by the difference of the two `DateTime` objects (using the `.Subtract` method).

Something like:

```
private static void ReadTextFile()
{
    var lastDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    // Open the text file
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\Users\rufusl\Documents\temp.txt"))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            DateTime currentDateTime;

            // Read each line and trim the extra spaces and 'Ok' from 
            // the end so we can parse the text into a DateTime object
            if (DateTime.TryParse(reader.ReadLine().TrimEnd('O', 'k', ' '), 
                out currentDateTime))
            {
                // If we get here, we successfully parsed the date time and set it 
                // to 'currentDateTime'. Now we see if the lastDateTime has been set. 
                // If it has, we do the comparison
                if (!lastDateTime.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
                {
                    // See if the difference between the last date
                    // and the current date is more than 5 minutes
                    if (currentDateTime.Subtract(lastDateTime).TotalMinutes > 5)
                    {
                        // Write the values out to the console window
                        Console.WriteLine(lastDateTime);
                        Console.WriteLine(currentDateTime);
                    }
                }

                // Set the last date to the current date
                lastDateTime = currentDateTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose that you have your first file in `string`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string textFile = @"08/12/2014 00:59:41   Ok
08/12/2014 01:05:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:10:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:15:02   Ok
08/12/2014 01:20:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:25:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:30:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:35:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:40:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:45:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:50:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:55:01   Ok
08/12/2014 02:00:01   Ok";

        textFile = textFile.Replace("\r", "");
        textFile = textFile.Replace("Ok", "");

        string[] lines = textFile.Split('\n');

        int loopRange = 0;
        if(lines.Length % 2 !=0)
        {
            loopRange = lines.Length - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            loopRange = lines.Length;
        }


        List<DateTime> newList = new List<DateTime>();
        for (int i = 0; i < loopRange; i += 2)
        {
            DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(lines[i]);
            DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(lines[i+1]);

            if(Math.Abs((date1 - date2).TotalMinutes) >= 5)
            {
                newList.Add(date1);
                newList.Add(date2);
            }
        }

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test1.txt");

        foreach (DateTime s in newList)
            tw.WriteLine(s);

        tw.Close();
    }
```

First you are removing `\r` from the string, after that the `OK`. You want to by two dates of your dates, that means if the number of Dates is not even you should remove one ! After that loop by two elements and take math.Abs value of difference between 2 values.

P.S Because I don't understand your question well, if you want to group one by one every date you will need to remove the `loopRange` variable and decreasing the list length and do it like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string textFile = @"08/12/2014 00:59:41   Ok
08/12/2014 01:05:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:10:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:15:02   Ok
08/12/2014 01:20:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:25:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:30:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:35:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:40:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:45:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:50:01   Ok
08/12/2014 01:55:01   Ok
08/12/2014 02:00:01   Ok";

        textFile = textFile.Replace("\r", "");
        textFile = textFile.Replace("Ok", "");

        string[] lines = textFile.Split('\n');


        List<DateTime> newList = new List<DateTime>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i ++)
        {
            if(i == lines.Length - 1)
               break;

            DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(lines[i]);
            DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(lines[i+1]);

            if(Math.Abs((date1 - date2).TotalMinutes) >= 5)
            {
                //I suppose that the second value is always bigger than the first
                newList.Add(date2);
            }
        }

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test1.txt");

        foreach (DateTime s in newList)
            tw.WriteLine(s);

        tw.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using LINQ:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt");

Func<string, DateTime> getDate = s => DateTime.Parse(s.Substring(0, 19));

var errors = lines.Skip(1)
                .Zip(lines, (current, prev) => new {current, prev})
                .Where(i => (getDate(i.current) - getDate(i.prev)) > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                .Select(i => new[] {i.prev, i.current, ""});

File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", errors.SelectMany(error => error));
```

Answer (score 0):

While I wrote this no one else had answered, now there are several good answers +1 to you guys. But here is mine since I wrote it I might as well post it.

```
            int counter = 0;
            string line;

            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
               new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\Intel\\times.txt");
            DateTime lineTime;
            DateTime lastTime = DateTime.MinValue;


            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(" ", 12));
                DateTime.TryParse(line, out lineTime);
                if (lastTime == DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    counter++;
                    lastTime = lineTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    var mins = lineTime.Subtract(lastTime).Minutes;
                    if (mins > 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                    counter++;
                    lastTime = lineTime;
                }
            }

            file.Close();

            // Suspend the screen.
            Console.ReadLine();
```